# Find the coefficient $c$ so the equation is even

Tags: trigonometry

Hello so I have been solving a task and I dont know how to solve it completely.The task says: Find the $c$ so that function $f(x) = 3\sin(2x +c) + 3$ is even. I know that if the function is odd this must be valid $3\sin(-2x + c) + 3 = 3\sin(+2x + c) + 3$ But i dont know how to find $c$?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you think of some other trig function that's even? How could you express that function in terms of sine?

Comment: Well $c=\pi/2$ may work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made up the equation correctly. Now you must solve it to find $c$:
$$3\sin(-2x + c) + 3 = 3\sin(+2x + c) + 3 \Rightarrow \\
\sin (-2x)\cos c+\sin c\cos (-2x)=\sin (2x)\cos c+\sin c\cos (2x) \Rightarrow \\
2\sin 2x\cos c=0 \Rightarrow \\
\cos c=0 \Rightarrow \\
\boxed{c=\frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi, k\in \mathbb Z}$$
Note: It was used the addition rule:
$$\sin(a+b)=\sin a\cos b+\cos a\sin b.$$
You can also use sum to product rule:
$$\sin a-\sin b=2\cos \frac{a+b}{2}\sin \frac{a-b}{2}.$$

Comment: thank you! But how did you got from sin(-2x)cosc + sinccos(-2x) = sin(2x)cosc + sinccos(2x) , I did the same thing today but i dont know if it is correct, i crossed out sincos(2x) and sincos(-2x) because cos(2x) = cos(-2x) also because sin(-2x) = sin(2x) i got to 2sin2xcosc=0 but i dont know is it allowed to crossout 2sin2x?

Comment: Note that $\cos (-2x)=\cos (2x)$ and $\sin (-2x)=-\sin (2x)$. Yes, it is allowed, because $x\in (-\infty,+\infty)$ and $c$ is constant.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$\sin(t)=\cos(\frac\pi2 - t)$$
And $\cos(x)$ is an even function.

Answer (score 0):

Even function: $f(-x)=f(x)$, i.e

$\sin (-2x+C)=\sin (2x+C)$;

1) $-2x+C = 2x+ C +2πk, k \in \mathbb{Z}.$

No condition for $C$.

$\small{2) -2x+C= (π - (2x  +C)) +2πk, k \in \mathbb{Z}.}$

$2C= π +2πk$  , $k \in \mathbb{Z}.$

$C=π/2 +πk$,  $k \in \mathbb{Z}$

Recall:

$\sin a = \sin b$ implies

1) $a= b +2πk$, $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, or

2) $a = (π-b) +2πk$, $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.